# One-loop Feynman integral over Euclidean momenta

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, integration, dimensional-regularization

I am trying to perform the following one-loop computation
$$
\int \frac{d^Dq}{(2\pi)^D} \frac{(k+q)^2 q^2}{((k+q)^2+m^2)(q^2+m^2)}
$$
where $k$ is fixed and everything is on the Euclidean setting, so there is no need to perform any Wick rotation.

I can not find the solution anywhere and I am not realizing how to do it by myself. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Use [Feynman parametrization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_parametrization). See e.g. Srednicki, chap. 14.

Comment: @Qmechanic Yeah I know. But my problem is more with the numerator...

Comment: Advice: Postpone dealing with the numerator.

Comment: maybe you can show us what you tried and where you get stuck....

Comment: @Oбжорoв I think I got it done! I will post the solution here during today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a couple years old, but I ran across it in a search, and it has a fairly simple answer. The trick for dealing with the numerator is
$$\int \frac{d^Dq}{(2\pi)^D} \frac{(k+q)^2 q^2}{((k+q)^2+m^2)(q^2+m^2)}=\int \frac{d^Dq}{(2\pi)^D} \frac{((k+q)^2+m^2-m^2)(q^2+m^2-m^2)}{((k+q)^2+m^2)(q^2+m^2)}$$
$$=\int \frac{d^Dq}{(2\pi)^D} \left[1-2m^2 \frac{1}{q^2+m^2}+m^4 \frac{1}{((k+q)^2+m^2)(q^2+m^2)}\right]$$
The first term in brackets vanishes in dim reg. The second and third terms are standard one loop integrals.